# shopify app development changing graphql API version

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify-app

I am trying to change the version of the graphql API the app is using.

setup:

- shopify CLI ver 2.15.6
- type node.js

in code I cannot see the URL the app is calling, is there an ENV or some server side
settings to change to the latest API version?

on next.js I see this on the server/client.js

```
export const createClient = (shop, accessToken) => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: `https://${shop}/admin/api/2019-10/graphql.json`,
```

but this is not used in embedded app bridge calls.

I would like to use the 2022-04 (latest) version

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialise it using the context, according to the [docs](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/HEAD/docs/getting_started.md#set-up-context)

> While setting up Context, you'll be able to set which version of the
> Admin API your app will be using.

```
Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY,
  SCOPES: [SCOPES],
  HOST_NAME: HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: {boolean},
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.{version} // all supported versions are available, as well as "unstable" and "unversioned"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @sajeetharan, is this a client-side or server-side version? I am after the ApolloClient API version.

Comment: This is on the client only. can you refer the docs?